# Commas are not allowed inside page item value? APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to pass a full name from 1 page to another.

But when I type 'Tyler, Brown' inside my text field and redirect to the next page.

[image]

The value that is left becomes 'Tyler'

[image]

What does apex not allow commas inside value of page item?

is there a way to go around this?

Answer (score 10):

Commas are used to separate multiple item values in an Apex URL, e.g.

```
http://host/ords/f?p=100:1:1234567890::::P1_ITEM1,P1_ITEM2:value1,value2
```

Typically you shouldn't be passing user-entered data via the URL - e.g. save the value in a table and pass a system-generated ID for the record instead.

If you must pass a value like this via the URL, you can surround it with backslashes (`\`), e.g.

```
http://host/ords/f?p=100:1:1234567890::::P1_ITEM1,P1_ITEM2:\value1,with,commas\,value2
```

Source: https://stewstools.wordpress.com/2008/02/05/apex-column-linking-with-data-that-includes-commas/ *(note: the links in this old article are dead, but I've tested the method myself on Apex 5 and it works)*